# Best way to get 'selling windows' for each product category in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

So my dataframe has sales details of many products for many years and graph kind of look like following:

[image]

And I'm trying to find out selling windows of each product.

### What I've tried so far:

The approach I thought of is to get the min, median and max date values for six month interval for each year and declare (min to median) as worst sellingperiod and median to max as the best selling window for that product. Code I'm using for six month now but want to get it for year wise as well. Whichever works best:

```
def dater(date):
    print(date)
    if type(date)==float:
        return '-'
    months = ['','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May','Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug','Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    period = ['Start', 'Mid', 'End','End']
    return months[date.month]+' '+period[date.day//10]


def grpRes(grp):
    return pd.Series([grp.Date.min(), grp.Date.max(), grp.Amount.mean()],
        index=['start', 'end', 'value'])


best_windows = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns)
for col in df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns:
    for year in ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']:
        print(f'For year {year} and category {col}')
        temp = df.loc[year,col][df[col]>=df[col].quantile(0.7)]
        print('temp created')
        if len(temp)>0:
            du = temp.reset_index().rename(columns = {'order_start_date': 'Date', col:'Amount'})
            res = du.groupby(du.Date.diff().dt.days.fillna(1, downcast='infer')
                .gt(20).cumsum()).apply(grpRes)
            res.index.name = 'chunk'
            for row in res.iterrows():
                print(row)
                best_windows.loc[year+' Window: '+str(row[0]+1)+' start',col] = row[1].start.date().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

I've then define windows based on values of all the years as starting range and end range of the windows. But seems like a horrible approach. This although gives me the date ranges for different years as follows:

```
    2017 Window: 1 end  2017 Window: 1 start    2017 Window: 2 end  2017 Window: 2 start    2018 Window: 1 end  2018 Window: 1 start    2018 Window: 2 end  2018 Window: 2 start    2018 Window: 3 end  2018 Window: 3 start    2019 Window: 1 end  2019 Window: 1 start    2019 Window: 2 end  2019 Window: 2 start    2019 Window: 3 end  2019 Window: 3 start    2020 Window: 1 end  2020 Window: 1 start    2020 Window: 2 end  2020 Window: 2 start    2020 Window: 3 end  2020 Window: 3 start    2020 Window: 4 end  2020 Window: 4 start
B                                           31-12-2019  08-11-2019                  09-01-2020  01-01-2020  31-07-2020  11-02-2020              
D   12-06-2017  13-05-2017  14-10-2017  16-08-2017  13-06-2018  24-05-2018  20-08-2018  11-07-2018  03-11-2018  27-09-2018  10-11-2019  22-10-2019  31-12-2019  28-12-2019          31-07-2020  01-01-2020                      
H                   06-04-2018  23-03-2018  09-08-2018  27-06-2018  16-11-2018  02-11-2018  25-05-2019  21-04-2019  15-08-2019  12-07-2019  31-12-2019  30-10-2019  31-07-2020  01-01-2020                      
J   12-02-2017  15-01-2017  31-12-2017  25-10-2017  11-02-2018  01-01-2018  31-12-2018  12-10-2018          24-02-2019  01-01-2019  31-12-2019  10-10-2019          04-02-2020  01-01-2020                      
L                   08-11-2018  03-11-2018  31-12-2018  06-12-2018          07-03-2019  01-01-2019  01-05-2019  24-04-2019  31-12-2019  02-09-2019  06-03-2020  01-01-2020  19-04-2020  10-04-2020  14-05-2020  10-05-2020  31-07-2020  26-07-2020
LO  31-12-2017  06-09-2017          03-01-2018  01-01-2018  31-12-2018  23-09-2018          10-02-2019  01-01-2019  31-12-2019  25-09-2019          11-02-2020  01-01-2020                      
M   11-09-2017  15-01-2017          15-10-2018  03-07-2018                  02-05-2019  22-04-2019  24-11-2019  18-11-2019          13-05-2020  28-03-2020  23-07-2020  21-06-2020              
P   03-05-2017  21-01-2017  19-10-2017  11-08-2017  23-04-2018  31-01-2018  10-10-2018  02-08-2018          23-04-2019  23-02-2019  06-10-2019  04-09-2019          04-04-2020  29-02-2020                      
S   26-07-2017  24-03-2017          01-07-2018  25-03-2018                  01-05-2019  18-04-2019  10-08-2019  23-05-2019          31-07-2020  01-04-2020                      
SH  12-08-2017  07-05-2017          11-08-2018  05-05-2018                  10-08-2019  01-05-2019                  31-07-2020  29-04-2020                      
SK                                          31-12-2019  12-12-2019                  01-01-2020  01-01-2020  31-07-2020  24-05-2020              
SKO 26-09-2017  01-05-2017          19-09-2018  03-05-2018                  25-07-2019  09-07-2019                  31-07-2020  04-05-2020                      
SL  10-06-2017  24-05-2017          06-05-2018  06-05-2018  16-07-2018  31-05-2018          01-08-2019  12-03-2019                  31-07-2020  16-02-2020                      
U                                           17-05-2019  18-04-2019  24-06-2019  10-06-2019          01-06-2020  27-03-2020  31-07-2020  25-06-2020              
V   13-02-2017  15-01-2017  31-12-2017  14-09-2017  05-03-2018  01-01-2018  31-12-2018  25-09-2018          19-02-2019  01-01-2019  31-12-2019  22-10-2019          22-01-2020  01-01-2020
```

Now I can use dater function I wrote to convert it into months & in precise month windows as well:

`best_windows = best_windows.transpose().applymap(dater)`

But this gives me year-wise solution not a single selling window.

### Ideally what I want to achieve:

Best selling and worst selling windows of each product during year which I can say hey during this time of the year, this product is popular (e.g. like product A sells best in end of March till middle of June) loosely defined by the crests/troughs of the % sales curve shown in the picture and ideally, transition period as well to have a better intuition of the selling windows of each product.

### Data Sample:

My data looks like following. Note that these are %s based on total sales value represented by each category. By % I meant, % in terms of total sales. Lets say total sales was of $10. Out of which product A was sold $5, B was $3 and C was $2. Then % values are as: A= 50%, B=30%, C=20%. This of course is only effective when there are more than one Products I tried to add a whole year data as it would better explain seasonality in my data which is not detectable in smaller samples.

Link: https://pern-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/syed_8911255_talmeez_pk/EY_w794N49dGgWfYal90ZLUBt5TDB3asJEayuJHD1QdRog?e=Ih4Wo8

Comment: A data sample would be highly helpful!

Comment: I have added a good large data sample

Comment: @piRSquared maybe you can help. Saw your great answer for time series on stocks and got the feeling that you might help

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
# usng sin to generate seasonal data
period = 365 * 4
dates = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=period)

np.random.seed(42)
pure = np.sin(np.linspace(6, 30, period))
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, period)
signal = pure + 20 + noise

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'signal': signal}).set_index('date')
df['smoothed'] = df['signal'].rolling(30).mean()

# get best/worst selling months
# rolling max/min method
threshold = 0.97
window = 320
df['best'] = df['smoothed'].where( df['smoothed'] > df['smoothed'].rolling(window).max() * threshold, other=np.nan)
df['worst'] = df['smoothed'].where( df['smoothed'] < df['smoothed'].rolling(window).min() / threshold, other=np.nan)
df.iloc[365:, 1:].plot(figsize=(14,10))
```

[image]

The rolling max/min bit isn't perfect, but is necessary if annual max/mins vary meaningfully from year to year. You also have to ignore the first year of data with this approach.

This next method resolves these issues by pulling the annual max/min separately first:

```
# annual max/min method
threshold = 0.97
df['max'], df['min'] = df['smoothed'].max(), df['smoothed'].min()
df['best'] = df['smoothed'].where( df['smoothed'] > df['max'] * threshold, other=np.nan)
df['worst'] = df['smoothed'].where( df['smoothed'] < df['min'] / threshold, other=np.nan)
df.iloc[365:, 1:-2].plot(figsize=(14,10))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @footfalcon I have converted them to % sales already so I think rolloing min/max should also work? Or I should do the annual approach keeping original values?

Comment: Its probably best to use the annual rather than rolling approach and use unadjusted data, but have a play around with it. Also, if you are looking for seasonality, you shouldn't use % change (if that's what you mean by % sales). For example, if my dummy data above was temperatures, the year-on-year % changes from the hot summer months would not be much different from the annual % changes in the winter months. That is to say, if you data has annual seasonality, calculating annual % change removes that seasonality from the data.

Comment: Nope by % I meant, % in terms of total sales. Lets say total sales was of $10. Out of which product A was sold $5, B was $3 and C was $2. Then % values are as: A= 50%, B=30%, C=20%. This of course is only effective when there are more than one Products

Comment: For non % sales it does not work. For % sales I'm trying to make it work tho. See what happens when I try for non% sales: https://ibb.co/HhnqP3x

Answer (score 0):

I think the first consideration here is whether you want a static model or you would want a self-updating kind of model.

My recommendation would be use static model as in use all data accumulated so far to get best-selling and worst selling windows of product and provide it as recommendation for next one year. Post that you could update your recommendation again.

Next, you need to decide on what you would want to call good and bad. May be something, top 20 percentile points are good %sales and bottom 20 are bad. Let's call this threshold T percentile.

Now to main part, so your hypothesis is there are fixed windows every year when %sales of a product are either high (above T) or low (below T).
So, firstly we need to get average values for each day of year(you could also fit a regression model instead of doing average, that would smooth things out and make your predictions more robust).

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df["dayofyear"] = df["datetime"].dt.dayofyear
df["year"] = df["datetime"].dt.year

dfg = df.groupby("dayofyear").mean()
```

Then, wherever average/predicted sales curve crosses T percentile, we start the interval and stop when it crosses again.

```
def get_thresh_crossing_intervals(arr):
    crossings = np.diff(np.sign(arr))
    # You might also want to wrap arrays to cover spans around end of year
    ends = np.where(crossings == -2)[0]
    starts = np.where(crossings == 2)[0][:len(ends)]  
    return list(zip(starts, ends))


def post_process_intervals(intervals):
    return [(p, q) for p, q in intervals if q-p>=7]


def get_col_intervals(df, col, top_thresh=0.2, bot_thresh=0.2):
    # Get quantile based thresholds
    top_qnt = df[col].quantile(1 - top_thresh)
    bot_qnt = df[col].quantile(bot_thresh)
    
    # Make threshold as zero line
    top_df = df[col] - top_qnt 
    bot_df = df[col] - bot_qnt
    
    # Get top crossings and intervals
    top_intervals = get_thresh_crossing_intervals(top_df)
    bot_intervals = get_thresh_crossing_intervals(bot_df)
    
    # Some post processings (e.g. only keep intervals with more than a week)
    top_intervals = post_process_intervals(top_intervals)
    bot_intervals = post_process_intervals(bot_intervals)
    
    return {'top_intervals': top_intervals, 'bot_intervals': bot_intervals}

product_intervals = {}
for col in ["A", "B"]:
    product_intervals[col] = get_col_intervals(dfg, col)


product_intervals
```

```
Sample Output:
{'A': {'top_intervals': [(15, 60), (117, 136)],
  'bot_intervals': [(1, 85), (103, 236), (273, 286), (287, 320)]},
 'B': {'top_intervals': [(120, 140), (198, 209), (306, 339)],
  'bot_intervals': [(36, 61), (80, 262)]}}
```

Additionally, we only keep intervals with more than certain length, otherwise we drop it or we can order intervals by their length/area under curve and keep top n.

**Note:**
If your time series are not stationary, you need to make them stationary first (Just check if year over year there is significant change in %sales of a product)

Comment: by % I meant, % in terms of total sales. Lets say total sales was of $10. Out of which product A was sold $5, B was $3 and C was $2. Then % values are as: A= 50%, B=30%, C=20%. This % is calculated for each day so there might not be a huge difference. There is a big YoY change but its being cancelled out using % sales. (As far as I think)

Comment: And  updated my attempt as well. With detailed code I have done so far and yes I took threshold to top 30%. I would prefer a static model too but as you can see there are different windows nt even close for  different years

Comment: If windows are really that different, then it might not be useful to calculate them year by year as it would not tell us  much about next year. Then how could we tell something like this product sells good in this time of year?